# How do I eliminate dynamic casts and switches, if the data class can't access the processing class?

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

I have a directed acyclic graph data structure, where there are multiple type of parent nodes and leafs. There is a function (`BuildGraph`), which emits this graph, and an other one processes it (`ProcessGraph`). The two functions are in separate `.cpp` files, but the `.h` file, where the data structure is defined, is included in both.

The `ProcessGraph` has many `switch` statements, which I can't replace with virtual functions, because the graph nodes can't have access on how they are processed. I would like to eliminate those `switch` statements, but I don't know how. What is the preferred way to solve a problem like this in C++?

The data structures:

```
enum NodeType {
    GROUP_TYPE_1 = 1,
    GROUP_TYPE_2 = 2,

    LEAF_TYPE_1 = 3,
    LEAF_TYPE_2 = 4,
    LEAF_TYPE_3 = 5
};

struct Node {
    const NodeType type;
    Node(NodeType _type) : type(_type) {}
    virtual ~Node() {}
};

struct Group {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
};

struct GroupNode1 : public Node, public Group {
    GroupNode1() : Node(GROUP_TYPE_1) {}
    /*...*/
};
struct GroupNode2 : public Node, public Group {
    GroupNode2() : Node(GROUP_TYPE_2) {}
    /*...*/
};

struct LeafNode1 : public Node {
    LeafNode1() : Node(LEAF_TYPE_1) {}
    /*...*/
};
struct LeafNode2 : public Node {
    LeafNode2() : Node(LEAF_TYPE_2) {}
    /*...*/
};
struct LeafNode3 : public Node {
    LeafNode3() : Node(LEAF_TYPE_3) {}
    /*...*/
};

struct Graph {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> root;
    /*...*/
};
```

BuildGraph:

```
Graph g;

// create a diamond shape
std::shared_ptr<GroupNode2> root = std::make_shared<GroupNode2>();
g.root = root;

std::shared_ptr<GroupNode1> c1 = std::make_shared<GroupNode1>();
root->nodes.push_back(c1);

std::shared_ptr<GroupNode2> c2 = std::make_shared<GroupNode2>();
root->nodes.push_back(c2);

std::shared_ptr<Node> l1 = std::make_shared<LeafNode2>();
c1->nodes.push_back(l1);
c2->nodes.push_back(l1);

return g;
```

ProcessGraph:

```
void ProcessGraph(std::shared_ptr<Node> root) {

    switch (root->type) {
        case NodeType::GROUP_TYPE_1:
        case NodeType::GROUP_TYPE_2:
        {
            Group* g = dynamic_cast<Group*>(root.get());
            for (std::shared_ptr<Node>& node : g->nodes) {
                ProcessGraph(node);
            }

            switch (root->type) {
                /* for each group type */
            }
        }
            break;

        case NodeType::LEAF_TYPE_1:
        {
            LeafNode1* l = dynamic_cast<LeafNode1*>(root.get());
            /* ... */
        }
            break;
        case NodeType::LEAF_TYPE_2:
        {
            LeafNode2* l = dynamic_cast<LeafNode2*>(root.get());
            /* ... */
        }
            break;

        case NodeType::LEAF_TYPE_3:
        {
            LeafNode3* l = dynamic_cast<LeafNode3*>(root.get());
            /* ... */
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than eliminate the switch statements, you could write functions for handling each `case` separately, and then you code will look much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

You could use visitor pattern for that. You would add an Apply function to your Node class and override it in each derived class to call the matching visit method in IVisitor interface. Then you implement one concrete visitor for each operation. Assuming that Node types are stable, this could be a good approach if you don't want to add all the operation in Node derived classes. Search the web, if you need code.

Comment: In my reputation, I don't see any downvote for that question. I don't think it is possible to know, so don't assume...